# Uploaded File could not be moved

Tags: wordpress, apache, macros

I am working with Mac Book Pro with OS X 10.9.4

I am trying to upload the theme in Wordpress but it's showing me this message

"The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2014/09."

I have already changed the permission's of the folder htdocs, mywebsite folder, upload folder also configured http.conf file of apache server.

I am strucked with this issue from last 2 hours, read many blog's all are saying to change the permission rights but not working

Answer (score -2):

if you can't solve the problem 
please try
go to setting wordpress - media

don't cheklist Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders
save changes
i solve the problem